# export a symbol for multiple projects in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a way for me to export a symbol from the library so I can use it in multiple files without having to add the symbol to each library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export it into a linked library (swc file)

then include the swc in your other projects

here;s a link that gives more detail:   http://www.theflashstudio.net/articles/swcFile.php